# How do I view disk usage on my desktop computer icon?

Tags: macos, mac

How do I get disk usage information on my 'Machintosh HD' icon on my desktop?

I did it on my old computer, so I know it's possible, but can't seem to find the option again.

I am on MacOSX 10.8.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right-click a blank location (e.g. not on an icon) on your desktop and click 'Show View Options'.

Check the 'Show item info' box:

[image: Desktop View Options]

The effect happens immediately.

Comment: Doing `Command`+`J` will Show the View options too.

Answer (score -2):

Command i will show you the info panel for any file or folder in finder

Comment: While true, this doesn't answer the OP's question.